# Output result to log file instead of console

Tags: c#, .net

Essentially i have this code and currently it prints to the console could someone modify the code so that it creates a log file in the same directory with the data instead

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;

class CSharpExample
{
  private static string API_KEY = "SAMPLE-KEY";

  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    try
    {
    Console.WriteLine(makeAPICall());
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
  }

  static string makeAPICall()
  {
    var URL = new UriBuilder("https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest");

    var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
    queryString["start"] = "1";
    queryString["limit"] = "5000";
    queryString["convert"] = "USD";

    URL.Query = queryString.ToString();

    var client = new WebClient();
    client.Headers.Add("X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY", API_KEY);
    client.Headers.Add("Accepts", "application/json");
    return client.DownloadString(URL.ToString());

  }
}
```

Comment: I understand your concerns but I'm not a very avid proggramer And if someone modifys the code rather than just simply give an awnser it helps me understand a lot this is my first ever c# program so I apologize and I'll try not to do that again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `File.AppendAllText` instead of `Console.WriteLine` to append text to a file (and it will create the file if it doesn't exist) instead of writing it to the console window. Pass the file path (or just the file name) as the first argument, and the text you want to add as the second argument. If you just pass a file name, it will use the path of your executable as the path.

Note that I added `+ Environment.NewLine` to the end of the string so that each call writes a new line to the file instead of appending directly to the last line in the file.

For example:

```
File.AppendAllText("Program_Log.txt", makeAPICall() + Environment.NewLine);
```

After running this line of code, I now have a file named `"Program_Log.txt"` created in my debug directory (because I was running it from Visual Studio in debug mode) that has the result of the `makeAPICall` method written to it.